# PHP CURL Post Fields is not working

Tags: php, curl

PHP curl post is not working..

Here's my code

```
   function post_to_url($url, $data) {
   $fields = '';
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');

   $post = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($post);

   curl_close($post);
}

post_to_url("http://www.i-autosurf.com/signup.php",$data);
```

can you please checkout the error..

is the code going wrong or is there anything different in website.

Comment: `$fields` is also allowed to be an array

Comment: For future reference, add your error and show you what you have tried to do already - don't just ask for debug and code

Comment: @learningpython you can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array with fields as is. Try

```
function post_to_url($url, $fields) {
    $post = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($post);

    curl_close($post);
}
```

Comment: not working dude !! i didn't get the confirmation mail

Comment: $data = array(
   "name" => "learningphp",
   "email1" => "anything@gmail.com",
   "email2" => "anything@gmail.com",
   "passwd" => "anything",
   "sitename" => "anything",
   "url" => "anything.com",
   "termscheck" => "0"
);

Comment: Show what's in `$result` after exec.

Comment: Also, "termscheck" should be `1`.

Comment: there is nothing in result just two or three blank lines

Comment: So obviously the issue is on that site's side, there could be some kind of protection. Quite sure `curl` works as expected. You can try the same script on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 $postfields = http_build_query($data);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: not working i am not getting the confirmation mail

Comment: try setting this option also curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); if this helps